# swift: in-app purchase

Tags: ios, swift, button

Нужно на кнопке показать стоимость встроенной покупки в валюте страны покупателя.

Для России мой текст выглядит так: 299.00 RUB

1. Как посмотреть как выглядит покупка для США?
2. Как вместо RUB поставить знак ₽ или вместо USD знак $?

Мой код:

```
func productsRequest (_ request: SKProductsRequest, didReceive response: SKProductsResponse) {

    let count : Int = response.products.count
    if (count>0) {
        let validProduct: SKProduct = response.products[0] as SKProduct
        if (validProduct.productIdentifier == self.product_id) {
            print(validProduct.localizedTitle)
            print(validProduct.localizedDescription)
            print(validProduct.price)
            buyProduct(product: validProduct);

            let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
            numberFormatter.formatterBehavior = .behavior10_4
            numberFormatter.numberStyle = .currency
            numberFormatter.locale = validProduct.priceLocale
            let price = numberFormatter.string(from: validProduct.price)
            self.buyButton.setTitle(price, for: .normal)
            NSLog("The price of this product is \(validProduct.price)")
        } else {
            print(validProduct.productIdentifier)
        }
    } else {
        print("nothing")
    }
}
```

UPD

```
func buyProduct(product: SKProduct){
    print("Sending the Payment Request to Apple");
    let payment = SKPayment(product: product)
    let price = localizedPriceForProduct(product)
    buyButton.setTitle("\(price)", for: .normal)
    SKPaymentQueue.default().add(payment);

}

func localizedPriceForProduct(_ product:SKProduct) -> String {
    let priceFormatter = NumberFormatter()
    priceFormatter.formatterBehavior = NumberFormatter.Behavior.behavior10_4

    priceFormatter.numberStyle = NumberFormatter.Style.currencyISOCode
    //эта строка отвечает за формат написания (USD или $ использовать .currency)

    priceFormatter.locale = product.priceLocale
    return priceFormatter.string(from: product.price)!
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
func localizedPriceForProduct(_ product:SKProduct) -> String {
    let priceFormatter = NumberFormatter()
    priceFormatter.formatterBehavior = NumberFormatter.Behavior.behavior10_4

    priceFormatter.numberStyle = NumberFormatter.Style.currencyISOCode
   //эта строка отвечает за формат написания (USD или $ использовать .currency)

    priceFormatter.locale = product.priceLocale
    return priceFormatter.string(from: product.price)!
}
```

Вызовите функцию:

```
 var product = SKProduct()
 ...
 let price = localizedPriceForProduct(product)
```

Comment: На этой строчке вылетает `priceFormatter.locale = product.priceLocale`

Comment: а product получен? он не nill?

Comment: Не вылетает. Добавил новый код в вопрос в UPD. При таком коде получаю цену 299.00 RUB, а нужно 299.00 ₽

Comment: тогда так:  priceFormatter.numberStyle = NumberFormatter.Style.currency

Comment: Ничего не изменилось. Вот это заменяет аббревиатуру

 `for identifier in ["en_US", "fr_FR",] { numberFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: identifier)}` 

Но не удобно писать каждый `identifier ` под каждую страну.

Comment: Проверь не на эмуляторе, а на устройстве. У меня строка NumberFormatter.Style.currency показывает ₽, $. Или .currencyISOCode покажет RUB или USD.

Comment: Да, все работает. Спасибо. Но есть еще проблема. Когда перехожу в контроллер с покупкой то текст со стоимостью покупки появляется через 5 секунд. Можно каким-то образом мгновенно показать текст со стоимостью?

Comment: Сам запрос на продукт нужно сделать за ранее, до перехода в контроллер ваших Покупок, у меня глобальная переменная var productsIAP: [String: SKProduct]! во  ViewController, в неё получаем список покупок в AppDelegate         IAPHelper.sharedInstance.requestProductsWithCompletionHandler({
            (value, products) in
            productsIAP = IAPHelper.sharedInstance.productList })
и когда уже пользователь перешел на контроллер Покупок то уже все будет готово для отображения (возможно).

Answer (score 2):

1) посмотреть какой банк предоставляет API для перевода валют по текущему курсу. И использовать этот API

2) использовать replacingOccurrences

```
let aString = "100 USD!"
let newString = aString.replacingOccurrences(of: "USD", with: "$", options: .literal, range: nil)
```

Comment: Я должен использовать replacingOccurrences  для каждой аббревиатуры во всех странах? Видел в App Store одни и те же приложения, но стоимость в валюте разных страны. Например: 299.00 ₽ или $2.99. В случае с долларом символ стоит впереди. А в Вашем ответе символ будет стоять позади. Что-то совсем запутался. Есть способ автоматически ставить символ в нужно месте и в валюте страны?

Comment: если речь идет о in-app purchases, там в зависимости от страны все должно само работать, и от вас ничего не надо